# How Can I install rethinkdb on Fedora 26 using docker?

Tags: docker, fedora, rethinkdb, fedora-26

I followed the following tutorial https://store.docker.com/images/rethinkdb  but I can not see the ip address.What is the problem?

[The result is empty after I execute the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTo9Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your containers are exited so you won't be able to contact them anyway.
Second: containers will be available on localhost and respond to the ports you map with the `-p` flag, so `-p 12345:80` will map port 80 in the container to 12345 on your machine, meaning you can connect on `localhost:12345`.